# What are the common tennis terms in Portuguese?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, tradução-inglês

Particularly for:

- [advantage set / tiebreaker set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_scoring_system#Scoring_a_tiebreak_game)
- game
- set
- match
- love (the term used for 0 or a no score situation)
- 15/30/40
- deuce
- advantage in / advantage out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a distinction in sports terms between the two major translation markets. In Brazilian Portuguese, the main trend is to keep it as close as the English term as possible:

> - "tiebreak" (sometimes "tiebreak**er**") for `tiebreaker set`
> - "game" / "game point" for `game / game point`
> - "set" / "set point" for `set / set point`
> - "partida" or "jogo" / "match point" for `match / match point`
> - "deuce" for `deuce`
> - "bye" for `bye` (when a player advances without having to play)
> - "wildcard" for `wildcard`

In European Portuguese, it is generally preferred to find a local expression whenever it is possible:

> - "set decisivo" for `tiebreaker set`
> - "jogo" / "ponto do jogo" for `game / game point`
> - "set" / "ponto do set" for `set / set point`
> - "partida" / "ponto da partida" for `match / match point`
> - "iguais" for `deuce`
> - "avanço automático" for `bye` (when a player advances without having to play)
> - "coringa" for `wildcard`

However, due to geopolitical and economical influences, the Brazilian *mindset* is gaining ground over the European one, and quickly. I want to keep this answer as short as possible, but I can comment on them if you believe they are needed for context.

Terms which are common for both countries:

> - "vantagem confirmada" for `advantage set`
> - "zero" for `love` (but "zero a zero" for `0-0`)
> - all numbers are said in local language:
>
>   - "quinze" or "15" for 15
>   - "trinta" or "30" for 30
>   - "quarenta" or "40" for 40
>       <sub>OBS: Portuguese language prefers numbers written in full.</sub>
> - "vantagem" for both `advantage in / advantage out`
> - "break point" / "duplo break point" / "triplo break point" for `break point / double break point / triple break point`
> - "ace" for `ace`
> - "falta" / "falta dupla" for `fault / double fault`
> - "quadra de grama" / "quadra de saibro" / "quadra de cimento" for `grass court / clay court / hard court`
>     <sub>OBS: it is usual to drop the "quadra de", e.g., "Roland Garros é
>     jogado no saibro" for `Roland Garros is played on clay courts`</sub>
> - "serviço" / "primeiro serviço" / "segundo serviço" for `service / first service / second service`
> - "fora" for `out`
> - "voleio" / "largadinha" for `volley` / `drop shot`
>     <sub>OBS: every other play is called by its English name: "stroke", "slice",
>     "smash", "lob"...</sub>

Comment: "In European Portuguese, it is generally preferred to find a local expression whenever it is possible"? What?

Comment: @JorgeB. There are way more properly translated terms in PT-PT than in PT-BR, not only in sports. Perhaps a biased point of view, but that's how it looks like.

Comment: Ramon that's not true, in tennis like in IT we use mostly English terms like «game point», «set por tiebreak», «framework», «layout»,etc. You can't assume that us will translate everything. You can't answer based on your  guess... Like «set decisivo» I never heard here. We don't use «voleio» we use «volley» instead. You have a lot of mistakes on pt_PT and in your "common" guesses...

Comment: Em Portugal não temos estas palavras: curinga; quadra; voleio; largadinha. A não ser que os tenhamos só para o ténis?

Answer (score 1):

We use some English terms in Portugal like *tiebreak* and *set* but you can use all terms in English we will understand them.

- set por vantagem / set por *tiebreak*
- jogo     (game point  = ponto de jogo   )
- *set*    (set point   = ponto de *set*  )
- partida  (match point = ponto de partida)
- love (don't know, maybe «zero»)
- 15/30/40
- iguais
- vantagem a favor / vantagem contra